# Is there any alternative for field collection translation with unlimited values?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, entities

I have a [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) with unlimited values and is translated under [Synchronize translations](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279460). I'm getting error when trying to save the translation node. From research I got the information that **FC with unlimited values** has problem with translation.

Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, Abin. Are you asking for a workaround for a known bug? Do you have links to share from your research? What is the error? More info is definitely needed.

Comment: This is from FC's readme.txt. **Restrictions
---As of now, the field collection field does not properly respect field
    translation. Thus, for now it is suggested to only use the field for
    entities that are not translatable.**  Plz refer [link 1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1344672),[link2](https://www.drupal.org/node/2059763)

Comment: I am looking to achieve this using any other modules or combination of  other modules.. ie without using field collection. Now  i am trying with [Double Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) and [Composed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/composed_field).